# What are the pros and cons of an embedded UITableViewController over a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, container-view

I'm creating my first iPad app and I have a UIView which has a table as well as other views.
I've noticed I have the option of creating a 'Container View' in which I can then embed a UITableViewContoller.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of embedding a UITableViewContoller rather than just using a UITableView?

Answer (score 2):

A UITableViewController adds some subtle (but helpful) functionality that using a UITableView by itself does not have.

Some examples (I don't know if this is a complete list, there may be more):

- in viewWillAppear, clears and reloads the table automatically
- In viewWillAppear, it flashes the scroll indicators to indicate the view is scrollable
- if you have edit fields in your UITableView, it will automatically scroll the table to the appropriate location when the Keyboard is displayed.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

A UiTableViewController is simply a subclassed UIViewController which has a UITableView as its "view". The benefits of using it are having the boiler plate code written for you and having less setup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a big disadvantage of using a Container View and embedding: it only works on iOS 6+. Trying to run a storyboard with an embedded Container View on iOS 5 results in the error message "Could not instantiate class named UIStoryboardEmbedSegueTemplate"

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController is your only option for static/grouped cells.